# Prove that $y=-\tan^{-1}(x)$ is a decreasing function with out the help of calculus.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

**Motivation:-**

I was disproving the statement" If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ a decreasing function. then, f is surjection. " I could able to prove this by calculus. But the question is pre-calculus level. I am practicing my old books.

**Attempt:-**

Let $$x<y\implies y-x>0.$$
Consider $$-\tan^{-1}(x)-(-\tan^{-1}(y))=\tan^{-1}(y)-\tan^{-1}(x)=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y-x}{1+xy}\right)$$

The sign of $1+xy $ depends on the value of $x$ and $y$. I don't know how to proceed from here now. Please give some hints.

Comment: Yet another "show this function is doing something without using calculus" question.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: what's the problem with this kind of question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let us prove first the tangent function $\tan:(-\pi/2,\pi/2)\to\mathbb{R}$ is increasing. Indeed, if $x > y$, one has
\begin{align*}
\tan(x) - \tan(y) & = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} - \frac{\sin(y)}{\cos(y)}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin(x)\cos(y) - \sin(y)\cos(x)}{\cos(x)\cos(y)}\\\\
& = \frac{\sin(x - y)}{\cos(x)\cos(y)} > 0
\end{align*}
because $0 < x - y < \pi$, $\cos(x) > 0$, $\cos(y) > 0$ and we are done.

Let us consider its inverse this time: $\arctan:\mathbb{R}\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. We need to prove it is increasing.

If we suppose by contradiction that $x > y$ and $\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) \leq 0$, we arrive at the conclusion:
\begin{align*}
\arctan(x) - \arctan(y) \leq 0 & \Rightarrow \arctan(x) \leq \arctan(y)\\\\
& \Rightarrow \tan(\arctan(x)) \leq \tan(\arctan(y))\\\\
& \Rightarrow x \leq y
\end{align*}
Then it can be deduced that the $\arctan$ function is increasing (hence $-\arctan(x)$ is strictly decreasing).

Hopefully this helps!